# iterate over array using shell scripting and print it using php

Tags: php, shell

i'm learning the shell scripting using php

### shell.sh

```
`#!/bin/bash

    BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
    echo "BASE DIRECTOY $BASEDIR"           ## get base directory
    echo "PRESENT WORKING DIRECTORY $PWD"   ## get present working directory

    declare arr="`dir`"
    echo $arr

   for i in $arr
   do 
       echo $i
   done`
```

And i'm executing this shell script using php script

### phpshell.php

```
`error_reporting(1);
    $output = shell_exec('sh shell.sh');
    echo $output;`
```

So when i'm echoing $arr in shell script, its working fine
but when i applying for loop on same array in shell script, it's not printing file names

### output

```
BASE DIRECTOY .
PRESENT WORKING DIRECTORY /cygdrive/c/wamp/www/shell
Copy\ of\ shell.sh htaccess new phpshell.php shell.sh
```

i tried all answers from stackoverflow and internet but no one solution is working.
i'm running this code on wampserver and windows xp sp2.
Also i installed a cygwin utility. i think there is no problem with cygwin

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phpshell.php, start by changing

```
$output = shell_exec('sh shell.sh');
```

to

```
$output = shell_exec('bash shell.sh');
```

The old Bourne shell (sh) doesn't understand 'declare'. I guess you got the error message

```
shell.sh: declare: not found
```

Another way to solve it is to remove declare from shell.sh.

(Your listings look a bit odd. Why do you frame all code with back-ticks?)